# How to create a dictionary of dictionary from a dataframe grouped by a certain column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a dataframe that looks like this.

```
      username   course      marks
0     alex       physics      20
1     bob        chemistry    25
2     alex       math         30
3     alex       chemistry    40
```

I want to get a list of nested dictionary that will look like this.

```
[{
   "alex":{
            "course":"physics",
            "marks":20
          },
          {
            "course":"math",
            "marks":30
          },
          {
            "course":"chemistry",
            "marks":40
          }
},
{ "bob":{
            "course":"chemistry",
            "marks":25
          }
}]
```

I tried using `groupby()` but was not able to get expected results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use custom lambda function with [`DataFrame.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) in [`GroupBy.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) and last use [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html):

```
d = (df.groupby('username')[['course','marks']]
       .apply(lambda x: x.to_dict('records'))
       .to_dict())
```

Or:

```
d = {name: g[['course','marks']].to_dict('records') for name, g in df.groupby('username')}

print (d)
{'alex': [{'course': 'physics', 'marks': 20}, 
          {'course': 'math', 'marks': 30},
          {'course': 'chemistry', 'marks': 40}], 
 'bob': [{'course': 'chemistry', 'marks': 25}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below to get the desired output

```
import pandas as pd

# create the DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'username': ['alex', 'bob', 'alex', 'alex'],
    'course': ['physics', 'chemistry', 'math', 'chemistry'],
    'marks': [20, 25, 30, 40]
})

# group the DataFrame by username
grouped = df.groupby('username')

# create a list of nested dictionaries
result_list = []
for name, group in grouped:
    # create a dictionary for the current username
    user_dict = {}
    for _, row in group.iterrows():
        # add the course and marks for the current row to the user_dict
        user_dict[row['course']] = {
            'course': row['course'],
            'marks': row['marks']
        }
    # add the user_dict to the result list
    result_list.append({name: list(user_dict.values())})

print(result_list)
```

Output:

```
[
    {
        'alex': [
            {'course': 'physics', 'marks': 20},
            {'course': 'math', 'marks': 30},
            {'course': 'chemistry', 'marks': 40}
        ]
    },
    {
        'bob': [
            {'course': 'chemistry', 'marks': 25}
        ]
    }
]
```